# Magento: .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento

I am running Magento Community Edition version 1.7.0.2.
I would like to know, how come are there *two* .htaccess
files in my installation, one in the magento root directory,
and another one in the magento app directory just beneath
the magento root directory?

On my system the first one is 209 lines long whereas the
second one only contains two directives.

Can anyone please explain how come there are two files
instead of one. Are both parsed or just one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly each .htaccess-File paresed, cause they could be used additional.

The last .htaccess-File may overwrite or enhanced previuos ones.

Comment: So, basically, if a file is accessed as http:// foobar.com/foo1/foo2/foo3/bar.html then the server looks for foo1/.htaccess, foo1/foo2/.htaccess, then foo1/foo2/foo3/.htaccess, and extends and overwrites as these are parsed, is this correct?

Comment: Well, if this is the case, then why is there an app/.htaccess? I haven't seen anyone access say http:// localhost/magento/app ... Any idea what that separate .htaccess file does?

Comment: In the /app folder the .htaccess have this inside:  
  
Order deny,allow  
Deny from all  

This is, if those Folders not outside your document_root, "Deny from all" will deney the access via Browser-Address-Bar on th Folder <yourdomain.tld>/app (and all his subfolders, and all files inside those folders)

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file in app/ is used to "deny" all access to any file under app. Without this someone could access http://yourdomain.com/app/etc/local.xml and see your database credentials, among other bad things. A similar file should be present in var/ as well (to prevent viewing logs, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing file and try adding default new .htaccess file

[Magento default htaccess file](http://allhtaccess.info/magento-htaccess-file/)